# Uncaught SyntaxError: expected property name, got '&'

Tags: javascript, json, laravel

I tried to pass data from backend (laravel)
But somehow in the browser got this error

Backend code :

```
public function __invoke(Request $request)
{
    $productions = new \App\Services\ChartServices\ProductionChart;
    
    return view('home', [
        'title' => 'Home',
        'chartData' => json_encode($productions->generate())
    ]);
}
```

frontend :

```
const productionData = {{ $chartData }};
console.log(productionData);
```

got this error instead on my console :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected property name, got '&' 127.0.0.1:8000:290:33
```

PS the $productions is the instance of laravel eloquent result

Can someone give me the solution ?

Comment: try ```{!! $chartData !!}``` instead.

Comment: Don’t use json_encode when passing the data to your view, there is no need.

Comment: so just pass the data to view ? @Peppermintology

Comment: Correct, unless you have a particular reason for encoding the data it is not necessary.

Comment: tried it and it worked, thanks for the tip @Peppermintology

Comment: Limit your use of {!! !!} as it is used to escape data, meaning it was parse raw markup which is a potential security risk.

Comment: @Peppermintology but how ? if i remove the {!! !!}} then will produce that error

Comment: What type of data does your generate function return?

Comment: @Peppermintology object inside an array

Answer (score -1):

You got the error because of the data format.

The laravel blade template engine will automatically escape all of the data that you're passing to your view.

So, if you want to pass an array or an object to the view, you need to convert the array or object to JSON string.

You can do it by using the json_encode() function.

So, the solution that worked for me is to change my code from this:

```js
public function __invoke(Request $request)
{
    $productions = new \App\Services\ChartServices\ProductionChart;
    
    return view('home', [
        'title' => 'Home',
        'chartData' => $productions->generate()
    ]);
}
```

to this:

```js
public function __invoke(Request $request)
{
    $productions = new \App\Services\ChartServices\ProductionChart;
    
    return view('home', [
        'title' => 'Home',
        'chartData' => json_encode($productions->generate())
    ]);
}
```

Comment: your answer looks **exactly** like the code in the question